# Tomcat reloads JS resources only every 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, tomcat, reload

I am using Eclipse and Tomcat to work on a webapp. I use Eclipse to deploy my code changes automatically to Tomcat. It works well for Java classes: when I make a change to a .java file, I can see it immediately reflected on the web application, without restarting Tomcat (as long as it is running in debug mode).

But with JS files, I have to stop Tomcat, go through "Add and remove" menu of Tomcat, remove my WAR files, click ok, add them back and click ok again and restart Tomcat to see the changes appear. A simple restart or a clean won't solve the issue. I really need to remove the projects and add them again.

Worse is that it used to work. Do you have any idea about what could cause that?

Here is my Tomcat config:

[image: Tomcat configuration (updated)]

Do you see anything wrong? Can I provide more information?

**=== EDIT ===**

I checked the place where Eclipse copies the resources for Tomcat, and it appears the JS file IS updated. So it means Eclipse does correctly its job of copying the resources to the destination. Tomcat is not picking the changes.

**=== ANOTHER EDIT ===**

There is an internal cache in our application. I deactivated it and cleared it, but it does not solve the issue. It is not likely to come from there.

Also, since I have the issue, I have seen twice Tomcat pick up my changes, but only when I come back to the application after a long time...

**=== Some new information ===**

It appears that Tomcat finally picks up the changes... But only after 10 minutes.

**=== This is not an Eclipse issue either ===**

It is now clear this is not an Eclipse issue: I started Tomcat from the command line, using the same parameters than Eclipse.

Here is the command line I used:

```
/home/antoine/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java -Dcatalina.base=/home/antoine/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0 -Dcatalina.home=/home/antoine/opt/java/apache-tomcat-8.0.15 -Dwtp.deploy=/home/antoine/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/antoine/opt/java/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/endorsed -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=somepassword -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/antoine/opt/java/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/my.keystore -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/antoine/opt/java/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/antoine/opt/java/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/home/antoine/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_25/lib/tools.jar org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just your browser holding a cached copy of your js ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I checked with two different browsers with an empty cache :o(

Comment: What happens if you hit ctrl+shift+r in the browser to force a full reload?

Comment: Nothing, it keeps using the old JS file. I can also restart Tomcat without any effect. The only reliable way I have found to get Tomcat to reload is to stop it, remove the projects from Tomcat, add them again and start again.

Comment: Maybe there is a piece of configuration that I should show, but I have no idea what settings I could be missing.

Comment: I added some more information: it seems to come from Tomcat not picking the changes, rather than from Eclipse not copying the files.

Comment: There is an internal cache in our application. I deactivated this cache and cleared it, the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in fact I had an nginx in front of my Tomcat server. I recently changed the config file for a different reason. But the new version included a cache. Hence the issue.

At some point, I had proven the issue did not come from Eclipse, neither from our application, and I had reviewed Tomcat config and reinstalled it. It was necessarily nginx.

What gave it away was that I found my JS files had an HTTP status 304 not modified. That means some web server decided to answer that. If that was not Tomcat, then...

Answer (score 0):

Antoine, the java classes needs to be compiled and the server knows when there are a change in the compiled .class because the file changed.

In the case of js, html or css files, you can have it in your project in a resources folder and you only have to save it and make a refresh in browser to see the results. Normally, browsers save some data in cache and you need to clean the cache before making the refresh and see the results.

If cleaning the browser cache dont work, try to use firebug in firefox (for example) to debug js code and check where are the files in your resources folder. Probably your are using an old version or somethink like that.

You can open Tomcat Overview page clicking two times in the tomcat server (Servers view). In the tab publishing chose the option Automatically publish when resources change.

Comment: I do agree with you and originally it was working that way, but then it stopped. Also I checked many times my browser cache and it is not the cause of the issue. But thanks!

Comment: i change my answer. check it please.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I already checked in Firefox Developer Tool and Chrome Developer Tool (both, just in case...) and this is really the same file.

Comment: What makes it even more bizarre, is that after some time (not sure how much exactly yet, but more thant 10 minutes), it finally picks the change...

Comment: wohhhh.. You have the "build automatically" option checked? See it in Project -> build automatically.

Comment: Other option is cleanning the project and server after save the js file.

Comment: You try this options?

Comment: So yes, "Build automatically" is checked. As I wrote in one of my edits, Eclipse copies correctly the file to the deployment folder. I checked with a separate editor.
I tried cleaning but it does nothing. So it really looks like a cache somewhere, that refreshes every 10 minutes. I checked our own internal cache and deactivated it, but I still have the issue. Their might be some Tomcat cache, but I cannot find it until now.

Comment: You can clean the tomcat server and tomcat work directory to. Rigth click over tomcat server and you have this two options.

Comment: I change another time my answer. please check it.

Comment: I tried cleaning both (work directory and web app), but that does not change the issue.
Mu current publishing setting is already "Automatically publish". But my screenshot did not show that part of the config, so I updated it in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Reload browser cache `Ctrl+F5`. What happens in Firefox, Chrome?

Comment: As I said below and above, this is not a browser caching issue, I already tried in different browsers, after clearing the cache, Ctrl+F5, Ctrl+Shift+R... I get consistent results between browsers.